# POST JSON with PHP cURL

Tags: php, curl

I have the following php code

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->_agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this->_headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,  120);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $this->_cookie_file_path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $this->_cookie_file_path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{"folderId":"1","parameters":{"amount":3,"ascending":false,"offset":0,"sort":"date"}}');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
```

But I don't understand why is not working . The API that I'm posting the JSON to says that the parameters were not received . Is there anything wrong in my code ? I think the whole trick is on the JSON parameters... I'm not sure how to send them as I couldn't see any "nave->value" pair with the http analyzer as it usually appears in simple forms ... just that JSON code without any "name".

Comment: What's the sent Content-Type? And why don't you use `json_encode`?

Comment: @mario I tried with  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json')); and is not working either . By default I head the header set as       $headers = array(
      "Expect:",
); I don't see how it would work with json_encode

Comment: You will have to consult the API maintainer. We can only guess.

Comment: @mario   I added the debug info (firebug) on this link due the fact I couldn't post it on SO. It says that it was not formatted well(though I tried several times to "format it) http://pastebin.com/Ujdim8t8

Comment: If you have something that use this interface and actually works, then use a proxy and record it :p then find out what your script does different, and luke out all the differences ( fiddler proxy is great for this, it even support fake certificates/MITM attacks for spying on HTTPS encrypted connections, decoding of gzip/deflate, etc)

Answer (score 5):

You can try as follows.
Basically if we have a array of data then it should be `json encoded` using php `json_encode`. And you should also add `content-type` in `header` which can be defined in curl as `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));`

```
$data = array("country"=>"US","states"=>array("MHASASAS"=>"MH","XYZABABA"=>"XYZ"));
$postdata = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init($URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: It would be appreciated if you added some comments to the chunk of code.

Comment: "Basically if we have a array of data then it should be json encoded using php json_encode" — They don't. They have a string literal that contains valid JSON.

Comment: "And you should also add content-type" — In a comment on the question from 2011: They said they did that.

Answer (score 3):

you can use this and replace with

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{"folderId":"1","parameters":{"amount":3,"ascending":false,"offset":0,"sort":"date"}}');
```

use this

```
$Parameters = array(
    'MerchantCode'        => $MerchantCode,
    'PriceValue'          => $amount,
    'ReturnUrl'           => $callback,
    'InvoiceNumber'       => $resnum,
);

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($Parameters));
```

Answer (score 2):

If:you use post method,you should know that:

CURLOPT_POST    TRUE to do a regular HTTP POST. This POST is the normal application/x-www-form-urlencoded kind, most commonly used by HTML forms.

@see http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

So:you can do like this:

```
$ar_form = array('name'=>'PHPJungle','age'=>66,'gender'=>'male');
$poststr = http_build_query($ar_form ); # important

$options[CURLOPT_HTTPGET] = false;
$options[CURLOPT_POST] = true;
$options[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS] = $poststr ; //default type:application/x-www-from-urlencoded

curl_setopt_array ( $ch, $options );
# @todo your other codes
```

This is my class I have used for a long time.The class is based on PHP cURL.
It supports GET/POST，HTTP/HTTPS.

@see https://github.com/phpjungle/iHttp/

Comment: I usually use Fiddler to capture http request.Download-url:http://www.telerik.com/fiddler  It's great tool,it supports proxy etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can post a json data with curl like so:

Using Command Prompt:

```
    curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"folderId":"1","parameters":{"amount":3,"ascending":false,"offset":0,"sort":"date"}}' $url
```

Using PHP:

```
    $data = array("folderId"=>"1","parameters"=>array("amount"=>3,"ascending"=>false,"offset"=>0,"sort"=>"date"));
    $postdata = json_encode($data);
    OR
    $postdata = '{"folderId":"1","parameters":{"amount":3,"ascending":false,"offset":0,"sort":"date"}}';
    
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't set the content type, so the post data is being sent as form data. Try setting the content type to application/json.

If that doesn't work, try wrapping the json string with an array.

Comment: I added         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json'));
 and is still not working

Comment: Try using array('jsoncode') for the post field. If  that doesn't work, you'll need to provide the request headers or suffer blind guessing.

Comment: Please the debug info(firebug)  http://pastebin.com/Ujdim8t8
I added the debug info (firebug) on this link due the fact I couldn't post it on SO. It says that it was not formatted well(though I tried several times to "format it)

Comment: If you are submitting it from PHP, you shouldn't be able to see the HTTP request/response from Firebug.  Try the following: 1) Add this to your curlopt - `curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);`  2) After the curl_exec, output the request headers you sent: `var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT));`  Once we can see what you are actually requesting, it should be a lot easier to tell why you're getting back errors.

Comment: I added the http request/response from firebug to see how exactly it should work . I mean that I need to emulate that in PHP .

Comment: I added the log from php-curl on this link http://pastebin.com/Vrv01HBj . I also print_ the json code so you can see it at the log beginning

Answer (score 1):

```
$link = "http://test.domain/myquery";
   $json = '{"folderId":"1","parameters":{"amount":3,"ascending":false,"offset":0,"sort":"date"}}';
   $postdata = json_decode($json);
 echo openurl($link, $postdata);
```

This works as json decode converts a json string into array.

```
function openurl($url, $postvars = "") {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postvars);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, '3');
        $content = trim(curl_exec($ch));
        curl_close($ch);
        return $content;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

if your API endpoint using body for send request using json data may be you can use [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle) the doc is here [doc](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#sending-requests).

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
$client = new Client();
$request = $this->client->post($url,array(
            'content-type' => 'application/json'
    ),array());
$request->setBody($json_data);
$response = $request->send();
return $response;
```

hope this work.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it make by steps:

```
$data = array(
    'folderId'=>"1","parameters"=>array(
        "amount"=>"3","ascending"=>false,"offset"=>0,"sort"=>"date"
    )
);

$data_string = http_build_query($data);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($data));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$result = json_decode($result,true);
```

I don't know if you need the header. I think that by default it is already  `application/x-www-form-urlencode`

If it doesn't work, try changing the `$data` values in array. Think it helps. :)

Comment: Using http_build_query in the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, that this is the solution but this works for me when posting json, change the json from

```
'{"folderId":"1","parameters":{"amount":3,"ascending":false,"offset":0,"sort":"date"}}'
```

to

```
"{'folderId':'1','parameters':{'amount':3,'ascending':false,'offset':0,'sort':'date'}}"
```

The only change i made was the double quotes are now on the outside, that works for me but I'm obviously posting to a different server

Only other help I could offer is to download a network debugging tool such as `Fiddler` or `Charles` proxy and monitor the requests sent/received, it could be a case that something else is wrong in your code.

Hope i helped :)

Comment: "The only change i made was the double quotes are now on the outside" — The JSON is now invalid.

Answer (score 0):

first of all
please check the curl http status code

```
$http_code= curl_get_info($exec_res,CURL_HTTP_CODE);
```

then modify this request header set with post header API server add a recorder to log those request info.